# how to display datetime type to this format: date("F j, Y, g:i a");?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, non-well-formed

I used `datetime` type in my table but I don't know how to display this using this format:

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

to have it look like: November 9, 2012, 9:17 am

I've tried

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $row["date"]);
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   C:\wamp\www\crud_exer\content.php on line 69

What should I do?

Comment: http://php.net/date - Fix the error *"A non well formed numeric value encountered"*. What you've done so far for that?

Comment: What is the value of $row["date"]?

Comment: i don't know what it means.. sorry..

Comment: in inderting the date, i only used now()  & i did echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", $row["date"]); to display it supposedly so i don't really know what the error means..

Comment: strtotime($row["date"]) try like this

Comment: i tried strtotime($row["date"])  but nothing's printed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do this way:

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row["date"]));
```

[PHP: date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: wow! this worked! thanks much! ^_^  i'll accept your answer in 4 mins.. tc

Answer (score 2):

[date function](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) only accepts timestamp as parameter. Convert your date using [strtotime](http://hu1.php.net/strtotime) before passing to date function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = new DateTime($row["date"]);

echo $date->format('F j, Y, g:i a');
```

this should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

you missed `strtotime()`

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row["date"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using mysql timestamps.. try

```
$row['date'] = "2009-12-12 11:10:28"; // this is for example only - comment out when tested
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($row['date']));
```

Answer (score 0):

In php are function to format date, also that function is allias to DateTime::format()

```
echo date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
#output: 5:45pm on Saturday 24th March 2012
```

Comment: no.. it's still getting an error.. i copied yours & edited it to: <?php echo date_format($row["date"], 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y'); ?>  but ERROR now is Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in C:\wamp\www\crud_exer\content.php on line 69

Comment: your `$row["date"]` is string type, so you need convert string to date `strtotime($row["date"])`, try this code:
`echo date_format(strtotime($row["date"]), "F j, Y, g:i a");`